# Multi-part Who am I puzzle

Tags: riddle

Clue 1:

> Look in the night sky and you will see
>
> Many things that are shining brightly
>
> Groups of smart people often measure me
>
> To find the rate at which the celestials move away quickly

Clue 2:

> Step in and take a stand
>
> If you're in front of me, we can go to faraway lands
>
> But really, we'll still be in the same place
>
> Yet we can make it seem like we went to space

Clue 3:

> I'm often used to help build things
>
> Which might be strange because I don't even have limbs
>
> Neither am I made of pure metal or alloy
>
> I'm made on something used by a common schoolboy

Final:

> Putting all of the above together
>
> Make everything devoid of color
>
> Then look at one then look at two
>
> And you'll get some valuable clues
>
> As those things are some of the many parts of me
>
> Also know that keeping doctors away isn't my specialty

What am I?

To clarify a bit more, each of the first 3 clues are looking for a separate word, and once you have all 3 of these, the final clue should help you arrive to the answer. Also note that I'm not looking for an explanation of each line, but just a sentence or two explaining why each word you found fits with its clue.

Sorry if it's confusing, and if you have suggestions or edits or know better tags for these kinds of puzzles, don't hesitate to change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a

> Macbook

Clue 1:

> Red shift
>  Used by those smart people to measure distances and speeds of celestial objects.

Clue 2:

> Green screen
>  Step in front of it and you can apply special effects and such and make it seem like you went to space.

Clue 3:

> Blueprint
>  Made of paper (schoolboy), used to build things.

Final clue:

> Put them all together and remove the color.
>  Shift, Print, Screen.
>  Shift and print are on a keyboard, and the screen is the screen of the laptop!
>  Macintosh because of the doctor comment.

Comment: You're really close, take particular note of the end of the very last line in the puzzle

Comment: Check it now :D

Comment: A little colder now, focus particularly on the "isn't my specialty" part

Comment: Do you mean to say, more specifically, focus particularly on the "**isn't** my speciality" part? And that [Na nccyr n qnl xrrcf gur qbpgbe njnl](http://rot13.com)? If so it was basically correct before, no?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> I'd say you are the [Apple Logo on the far right](http://static.wixstatic.com/media/23e94b_6ece19ad319e4519be29406e38f3bce2.jpg/v1/fill/w_625,h_352/23e94b_6ece19ad319e4519be29406e38f3bce2.jpg).

Clue #1:

> Red shift is used to measure how quickly galaxies are receding.

Clue #2:

> The green screen is used by content creators to put actors in any locale or circumstance.

Clue #3:

> Paper blueprints.

Final:

> [The Red, Green, Blue, and the overlapping 2-combos of each](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/AdditiveColor.svg) make up the colors of the [logo on the extreme right](http://static.wixstatic.com/media/23e94b_6ece19ad319e4519be29406e38f3bce2.jpg/v1/fill/w_625,h_352/23e94b_6ece19ad319e4519be29406e38f3bce2.jpg). White would be the bite.